# read.table from write.table in R

Tags: r, gsub, read.table, write.table, qdap

I'm trying to do a `qdap::multigsub` in order to fix some typos, misspelled names, variant expressions and some other "aberrations" in a list of climatic event types (yes, it's the NOAA's data set on storms that belongs to an assignment in a coursera class on reproducible research; although this fixing is neither required nor expected in the assignment: it's me trying my best!).

So I have events named "flash flood", "flash flooding", "flash floods" and the like, and I'd like to group them all in a level called "flash flood". So what I did first was:

```
expr <- c("^flash.*floo.*","thun.*")
repl <- c("flash flood","thunderstorm")
```

Length of each vector is 51 and this is a `knitr` assignment, so in order to keep it readable (margin column=80), I had to go with something like

```
expr <- c(expr,"new_expr_1","new_expr_2")
repl <- c(repl,"new_repl_1","new_repl_2") # repeated many, many times
```

Which makes the code kind of messy. Of course, I have the complete `expr` and `repl` vectors, so I would like to have each pair (expr and repl) of correspondent values in a row, so the reader of the code would have an easy time (that's why `dput` won't work here: they don't align each pair of values).

I tried this:

```
a <- data.frame(expr=expr,repl=repl)
print(a,rownames=FALSE)
  # copying the output, and then
b <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="paste_text_here")
```

but it failed (I think because `print` throws the output without quotation marks and there are some two-word expr or repl). I also tried

```
write.table(a,rownames=FALSE)
  # copying the output, and then
b <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="paste_text_here")
```

but it doesn't work either (I think because `write.table` outputs each item between quotes, and `read.table` finds too many quotation marks to handle).

I'd like to have in my Rmarkdown file something like this:

```
exprRepl <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="expr repl
                                         expr_1 repl_1
                                         expr_2 repl_2")
```

How can I achieve this from the data I have now?

`dput` of the first 5 rows of data frame follow:

```
> dput(a[1:5,])
structure(list(expr = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("^BLIZZARD.*", 
"^FLASH.*FLOOD.*", "^HAIL.*", "^HEAVY.*RAIN.*", "^HURRICANE.*"
), class = "factor"), repl = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("BLIZZARD", 
"FLASH FLOOD", "HAIL", "HEAVY RAIN", "HURRICANE"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("expr", 
"repl"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

**If there's any other approach to replace the wrong/variant names, I'd be very happy to hear from it and give it a try!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use a singe quote `'` around the pasted text (this works as long as there are no `'` in your data):

```
d <- structure(list(expr = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("^BLIZZARD.*", 
"^FLASH.*FLOOD.*", "^HAIL.*", "^HEAVY.*RAIN.*", "^HURRICANE.*"
), class = "factor"), repl = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("BLIZZARD", 
"FLASH FLOOD", "HAIL", "HEAVY RAIN", "HURRICANE"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("expr", 
"repl"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

write.table(d, row.names=FALSE)

# copy paste output of write.table in text field below:
read.table(header = TRUE, text='"expr" "repl"
"^HURRICANE.*" "HURRICANE"
"^BLIZZARD.*" "BLIZZARD"
"^FLASH.*FLOOD.*" "FLASH FLOOD"
"^HAIL.*" "HAIL"
"^HEAVY.*RAIN.*" "HEAVY RAIN"')
```

Comment: Very simple solution, thanks!. Just for completion, this is in `?Quotes` (which I didn't even think of consulting!): "single quotes are normally only used to delimit character constants containing double quotes.".